# Is it possible to cast a list of reflected Types to their original strongly typed objects?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting

From the second line of the code below, I retrieve a List of Types. I would like to return this as a list of IBusinessObject. Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about doing this?

```
public List<IBusinessObject> RetrieveAllBusinessObjects()
{
    var businessObjectType= typeof(IBusinessObject);

    List<Type> implementationsOfBusinessObject = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
         .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
         .Where(businessObjectType.IsAssignableFrom).ToList();

    return ?;
}
```

Comment: You appear to be confusing types and instances. How do you want to go from `typeof(SpamBusinessObject)` to an object of type `SpamBusinessObject`? There may not even be such an object anywhere!

Comment: It is unclear, `Type` is different from `Instance`. `List<IBusinessObject>` holds instances where as `List<Type>` holds the type itself

Comment: Yes, great point - thanks! You are correct, I did mean instances. Me interchanging those non-interchangeable words prevented me from seeing the obvious answer. All I had was to create their respective instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a possible implementation that assumes that all the types have a default constructor.

```
public List<IBusinessObject> RetrieveAllBusinessObjects()
{
    var businessObjectType= typeof(IBusinessObject);

    List<Type> implementationsOfBusinessObject = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
         .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
         .Where(businessObjectType.IsAssignableFrom).ToList();

    return implementationsOfBusinessObject.Select(t => (IBusinessObject)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
}
```

I also suggest to check if the type is a class and is not abstract.

Usually when dealing with scenario like this it is better to use dependency injection container that can resolve all your dependencies. For example Castle Windsor as a typed factory facility that you can use to resolve all the instance that implement a specific interface. Look at http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx and http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Resolvers.ashx

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much! As the comments on my question indicated, I was attempting to create instances, not cast types.

Comment: (looking into the dependency injection solution now, hadn't considered that)