# What are the benefits of using Dependency Injection when retrieving implementations of an interface at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection

```
public List<IBusinessObject> RetrieveAllBusinessObjects()
{
    var businessObjectType= typeof(IBusinessObject);

    List<Type> implementationsOfBusinessObject = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
         .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
         .Where(businessObjectType.IsAssignableFrom).ToList();

    return implementationsOfBusinessObject.Select(t =>(IBusinessObject)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
}
```

I was suggested by a user on stack overflow that I should check out dependency injection as a workaround for the above snippit. What would be the benefits of this?

Just a little overview on what the scenario is:

Our database has little to no store procedures so we have begun implementing C# business objects for our more complicated tables. As we are hoping to switch databases some time soon this seems to be the best option. All of the business objects must be loaded using reflection at runtime to help manage them. All of these business objects implement the interface IBusinessObject.

The suggestion to use dependency injection came from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350073/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-list-of-reflected-types-to-their-original-strongly-type)

EDIT:

1. The RetrieveAllBusinessObjects method is in a class behind an interface so is directly testable
2. We use AutoFac if that changes anything. We don't use a separate config file.

-

Comment: DI would do the above without you having to write code to do it so there's less opportunity for you to introduce bugs. DI gives you many more benefits, but you'll need to evaluate those according to your needs.

Comment: @SimonHalsey you actually just answered my question. Could you write this as an answer so I could accept it? Also if possible go a tiny bit more in depth in case others discover this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using the code above, you simply use DI which is configured in the config file of the app but also sometimes you can decorate a property or a parameter in a method which will then be automatically injected in (by the mapping set up either programmatically or via config) when the request is made to access that object or when it is going to be invoked in the method being called in the params.

it also makes it a bit more testable in that you can create different concrete types which implement of an interface, then instead of having to recompile the code, you just flick the mappings by the config file and viola...all works.

Comment: We don't store our dependency injection in a separate config file, it is coded in C#. Also we would never really need to switch between different implementations of the same class. Each class would represent a single or group of related database tables. There would also be multiple business object implementations - all relevant.

Comment: right, but what I am getting at is that DI gives you that flexibility. From what you are describing, seems DI is NOT beneficial to your current working.

Answer (score 0):

DI would do the above without you having to write code to do it so there's less opportunity for you to introduce bugs.

DI gives you many more benefits such as

- Making it easier to test individual units of code. Dependencies can be mocked, so you can limit the code being tested
- Easy to understand the dependencies within your code. Dependencies generally get injected in certain places, usually the constructor.
- Linked to 1/ above, because you should now defined interfaces between your code, when your requirements change & you need to rewrite a component, you can do so with a higher level confidence that it will work with your existing code-base.

There are other benefits that others can probably describe better, but you'll need to evaluate those according to your needs.